# What's wrong with my pagination(Meteor)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

my router.js (i'm using iron-router):

```
...
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'postsList',
    increment: 4,
    postsLimit: function() {
        return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function() {
        return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
    },
    posts: function() {
        return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
    },
    data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
        var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
        return {
            posts: this.posts(),
            ready: this.postsSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
        };
    }
});
NewsController = PostsListController.extend({
    template: 'newsTemplate',
    increment: 2,
    limit: function() {
        return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function() {
        return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
    },
    posts: function() {
        return Posts.find({postType:'Новости'}, this.findOptions());
    },
    data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
        var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
        return {
            posts: this.posts(),
            ready: this.postsSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
        };
    }
});
Router.route('/news/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'newsTemplate',
    controller: NewsController
});

Router.route('/:postsLimit?', {
    name: 'postsList'
});
...
```

My template(same as index template, differ only in names):

```
<template name="newsTemplate">
    <div class="container main">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each posts}}
            {{> newsItem}}
        {{/each}}

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{#if nextPath}}
            <div class="row">
                <a class="load-more" href="{{nextPath}}" style="color: black;font-size: 1.3em;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Load more</button></a>
            </div>
        {{else}}
            {{#unless ready}}
                {{> spinner}}
            {{/unless}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

On index page(using PostsListController) it working good, but on url http://localhost:3000/news(using NewsController) :

- I'm getting properly posts, but button 'Load more' not working(Just doing nothing on click).

On url http://localhost:3000/news/2 (or news/1,3 etc.):

- it working fine and shows me the corrent amount of posts, button 'load more' is working too

What's the problem? Why button not working on http://localhost:3000/news ?

Comment: Are you using a specific package to handle pagination?  Do you have template events tied to the "Load more" button?  If so, post the javascript.

Comment: No, i'm using raw example from the book Discover Meteor (chapter Pagination)

Comment: That example has js (posts_list.js) which has a template helper (Template.postsList.events) for the button click.  Do you have a similar helper for your news template?

Comment: Here link: http://ru.discovermeteor.com/chapters/pagination/. This on russian, but you can just read code. So i can't see any words about template helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NewsController, you've changed the name of the postsLimit function to limit:

```
limit: function() {
    return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
},
```

But in your data function, you're still referring to this.postsLimit():

```
data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
        var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
        return {
            posts: this.posts(),
            ready: this.postsSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
        };
    }
```

Change your limit function to newsLimit to make it more clear, and then change the data function to use this.newsLimit().